# Can elements in a subset of the rational numbers be ordered from lowest to highest?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose there is a set defined as [0,1]$ \cap  \mathbb{Q}$ . I am wondering if it is conceptually possible to make an argument about ordering the numbers in this set in a sequence from lowest to highest, on the basis that rationals are countable. Like, for instance, in the case of the set of $ \mathbb{N} $ that seems easy - the first element of the sequence will be 1, the second one will be 2, etc. But even if I do not have an explicit algorithm for assigning each rational a spot in the sequence, can I still make a similar argument for the rationals?

Comment: You can order the rationals (i.e. define what $<$ means on $\Bbb Q$); they just won't be discrete (that is, they won't be like $r_1<r_2<r_3<\dotsb$). You can enumerate the rationals (you can have $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q=\{r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots\}$), but they won't be in order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we could list the rational elements of $[0,1]$ in order; specifically, suppose that $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} = \{ r_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ with
$$r_1 < r_2 < r_3 < \dots$$
Then we'd need $r_1 = 0$ and $r_2 > 0$. But then $\frac{r_2}{2}$ is a rational in $[0,1]$, so $r_2 = r_k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$; and moreover $k \ne 1$ since $r_1 = 0 \ne \frac{r_2}{2}$, and $k \ne 2$ since $r_k = r_2 \ne \frac{r_2}{2}$..

But then $r_1<r_k<r_2$ for some $k>2$, contradicting the assumption that $r_n<r_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The reason for this failure is that the rationals are *dense*; that is, given any rational numbers $a,b$ with $a<b$, there exists a rational number $c$ with $a<c<b$. For example, we can take $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$.